# How do I track a request and its corresponding model changes in Django?

Tags: django

Whenever a request is made I'd like to make a unique a tracking number.
Within `request_started` signal, I'm assuming to find out the authenticated user to track with the unique number.

If there is any database change, it would store the change set with the tracking number. `post_save`, `post_delete` and `m2m_changed` signals should be ok.

My questions are:

1. How do I make (or get if there is any) a unique tracking number for each request?
2. How do I get the authenticated user in `request_started` signal, like we do `request.user` in views?
3. How can I get the unique tracking number within `post_save`, `post_delete` and `m2m_changed` signals.

I'm on Django2.1 and python3.6.